# Dot operator acting weird

Tags: python

I am new to python app development. When I tried a code I'm not able to see its output. My sample code is:

```
class name:
    def __init__(self):
        x = ''
        y = ''
        print x,y
```

When i called the above function like

```
some = name()
some.x = 'yeah'
some.x.y = 'hell'
```

When i called `some.x` it works fine but when i called `some.x.y = 'hell'` it shows error like

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#5>", line 1, in <module>
    some.x.y = 'hell'
AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'y'
```

Hope you guys can help me out.

Comment: What are you waiting for some.x.y ? x and y are two discrete class variables.

Comment: @myildirim I JUST WANT TO use like some.x.y..is there any way to use like that ..if there is please post it as an answer

Comment: Why do you need it ? If you explain, maybe, we can help you.

Comment: @myildirim the thing is that i just want an example as an answer on how to use some.x.y = 'some thing' ..please edit your answer..:)

Comment: @user3843420 if you want to do that, make `some.x` a `name` instance. You can't add attributes to strings. Please pick a better title; the "dot operator" isn't "acting weird"; this is precisely the expected behaviour.

Comment: @user3843420 The dot operator is not acting weird. And some.x (ie a string) has no attribute y, but some (ie a "name") has the attribute y, as well as x for that matter.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, you are defining the class with the wrong way, you should;

```
class name:
    def __init__(self):
        self.x = ''
        self.y = ''
        print x,y
```

Then, you are calling the wrong way, you should;

```
some = name()
some.x = 'yeah'
some.y = 'hell'
```

The problem is, `x` and `y` are `strings`. If you want to `some.x.y` for some reason, you should define `x` on your own.In other words, you can't use `some.x.y` for now.

Ok, you still need for `some.x.y`;

```
class name:
    def __init__(self):
        pass

some = name()
some.x = name()
some.x.y = "foo"

print some.x.y
>>> foo
```

Comment: see i just want to use three varibales instead of two ..like some.x.y = 'some string'

Comment: can you edit ur answer to use like some.x.y by defining the x ..it would be helpful and i would accept it as answer

Comment: see you said If you want to some.x.y for some reason, you should define x on your own..so it would be helpful if u defined ur own x in an answer and show how some.x.y works

Comment: @myildirim this is not a good implementation; you know `x.__init__` never runs? You are setting a class attribute.

Comment: @jonrsharpe am going to ask another qus ..please see it

Comment: @jonrsharpe ye, i know that x.__init__ will never run and also i want to it.The solution is just for this question's requirement.

Comment: @myildirim but it is a solution so specific that you're bound the give the OP further problems, particularly as they seem to struggle with basic concepts.

Comment: @jonrsharpe i see, i just wanted to make it work.Anyway, updated the answer.

Comment: @myildirim but that doesn't really fix it. You're still stuck with all instance of `name` sharing the same `.x.y`. Also, `__set__` doesn't run either; you are modifying the class, instance methods are irrelevant. You might as well have `class x: pass`.

Comment: @jonrsharpe ok, as i understood, you are saying that X should be a seperate class and the composite relationship should be used ?

Comment: @myildirim see my comment on the question

Comment: @jonrsharpe What do you think, now?

Comment: @myildirim please have a lookhere http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24819749/cant-understand-dot-operator-concept

Answer (score 2):

`x` and `y` are two different variables on your instance `some`.

When you call `some.x`, you are returning the string `'yeah'`. And then you call `.y`, you are actually trying to do `'yeah'.y`, which is why it says string object has no attribute `y`.

So what you want to do is:

```
some = name()
some.x = 'hell'
some.y = 'yeah'
print some.x, some.y
```

Answer (score 0):

These are different variables. So when you do chain .y onto some.x you are looking for a member variable y of a string which does not exist

```
some = name()
some.x = 'yeah'
some.y = 'hell'
```

if you want to make a single string out of both x and y you can use + to concatenate them together as follows

```
s = some.x + ' ' + some.y
print s # prints out "yeah hell"

class name:
    def __init__(self):
        x = ''
        y = ''
    def ___str__(self):
        print x + ' ' y
```

now you can print the class and get

```
print some # prints "yeah hell"
```

Comment: see i just want to use three varibales instead of two ..like some.x.y = 'some string'

Comment: does that revision help?

Comment: no ..why are u not getting me what i want ..i just want to use like some.x.y = 'some string' ..so when we do like print some.x.y ..we must get output as some string

Comment: some.x.y does not make sense. some.x is a string and does not have a member .y that can be called or returned

Comment: can this be possible with int ??..so in python we cant do like some.x.y ??

Answer (score 0):

When you perform `some.x` you are no longer dealing with the `some`, you are dealing with the type that `some.x` is. Since `'foo'.y` doesn't make sense, you cannot do it with `some.x` either since it is of the same type as `'foo'`.

Comment: seee when i use like some.x.y i gets error like AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'y'

Comment: Yes. That's because you put a `str` in `some.x` previously. And `str` instances have no attribute called `y`, nor can you add one.

Comment: it would be really helpful if u edit ur answer ..showing in which situation we want to add like some.x.y ..

Comment: Uh... all you have to do is have `some.x` be a type that supports an attribute called `y`.

Comment: can you please update it as an answer ..i cant understand ,,if you update ur answer in code i can get it fastly..

Comment: **There is no code that will fix it. What you are trying is not possible in the first place, nor is it even sensible.**

Comment: so can we do like some.y.x instead of some.x.y

Comment: My answer doesn't change just because different names are being used.

Comment: @user3843420 Is this the actual problem that you're working on or is this part of something else? It would help a lot if you gave us more information on what you're doing.

Comment: so you say in python we cant use like some.x.y = 'some string' ??

Comment: You can. But you can't say `'foo'.y = 'some string'`.

Comment: @user3843420 `some.x.y` refers to a `y` that is contained inside the `x`, which itself is contained in `some`. If they are separate variables (like in your question), it makes no sense to say `some.x.y` because `y` is not contained inside `x`. Now, it *is* possible to make it so that `y` *is* contained in `x`, but it isn't clear if that's what you would actually need because we don't have context for your question.

Comment: yes ..but th first answer shows exactly what i want

Comment: @user3843420 `some.x.y` is the same as `(some.x).y` and `(some.x)` is the same as `'yeah'` in your example. This means that `some.x.y` is the same as `'yeah'.y`, which doesn't make sense and that's why the Python interpreter is giving an error.

Comment: @DavidYoung thanks now i got it ..and i got what i want in the first answer