# Cant understand dot operator concept

Tags: python

hey guys am really confused about the working of dot operator..The code which i have tried..

```
class Name:
    class x:
        def __init__(self,y):
            self.y = y
    def __init__(self):
        pass

some = Name()
some.x.y = 'foo'
print some.x.y
```

When i run this code it succesfully outputs `foo`.

But when i tried the code

```
class Name:
    class x:
        def __init__(self,y,z):
            self.y = y
            self.z = z
    def __init__(self):
        pass

some = Name()
some.x.y.z = 'foo'
print some.x.y.z
```

i get an error..how can i use like `some.x.y.z` and get the output as `foo`??..

Any useful help would be appreciated..Thanks

Comment: Don't you mean `self.x.z`?

Comment: You can use `some.x.y` and `some.x.z`. But `z` isn't inside `y`, so why would you expect `some.x.y.z` to work?

Comment: @Barmar can you please post it as an answer

Comment: @EdChum just like barmar said

Comment: Note that the `__init__` of your nested class is never called, because you never instantiate the class.  When you set ``some.x.y` you're setting a class attribute on `some.x`.  In some sense this doesn't matter, since `x` is itself a class variable, but it suggests you're not really understanding what your code is doing.  What are you trying to accomplish here?

Comment: @BrenBarn i just want to know can we do like some.x.y.z ?..if yes please post the code as an answer explain its working

Comment: @user3843420: Why do you want to do `some.x.y.z`? Rather than talking about syntax, can you describe the meaning of what you want to do?

Comment: The "dot operator", as you call it, is the syntax for accessing the attributes of an object: `object.attribute_name`. Why did you expect the second version to work? `some.x` is a *class*, not an *instance*; `x.__init__` never runs, so `y` isn't assigned.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is not clear why you expected the second code to work. The first code is bad, as it mixes up classes and instances: `some` is an *instance* of the *class* `Name`; `some.x` is a *class*, and also a *class attribute* of `Name`. If you create another `Name` instance, it will share the same attributes on `x`. Instead, consider this:

```
class Name(object):
    def __init__(self, x=None,
                 y=None, z=None):
        self.x = x
        self.y = y
        self.z = z

y = Name(z='foo')
x = Name(y=y)
some = Name(x=x)

##some = Name(x=Name(y=Name(z='foo'))) # one-line equivalent

print some.x.y.z # 'foo'
```

The result looks like:

```
 - some: Name
   - x: Name
     - x: None
     - y: Name
       - x: None
       - y: None
       - z: 'foo'
     - z: None
   - y: None
   - z: None
```

You can't try to access arbitrary chains of attributes `a.b.c.d` and expect them to work; you have to define the attributes your object should have (until you get into e.g. `__getattr__`, but let's not worry about that now). You can't add arbitrary attributes to e.g. strings or `None` (so you can't now set `some.x.y.z.foo = 'bar'`), although you can to your own classes (so you could set `some.x.y.bar = 'baz'`). However you can't do e.g. `some.x.y.foo.bar = 'baz'`, because `some.x.y.foo` doesn't exist (yet).

Comment: This is probably the highest ratio `quality(answer) / quality(question)` I've ever seen at SO, kudos to you :)